# In Smallville S04E11, how did Alicia know to use red kryptonite?

Tags: dc, smallville

In *Smallville* season 4 episode 11 "Unsafe", Alicia Baker (the teleporting girl from S03E14 "Obsession") is released from Belle Reve and about to start dating Clark again. When she offers him to run off to California and Clark hesitates, Alicia goes to the Torch office and finds the red kryptonite ring.

How did she know how the red kryptonite affects Clark? In "Obsession" she did overhear Clark talking to his parents and learn that green kryptonite makes him sick, but nothing about the red one. More to that, the only people who explicitly knew the effect of the red kryptonite are Clark's parents and Pete Ross, so it's highly unlikely that Alicia could have learned about that in Belle Reve.

As per their dialogue in the episode, Alicia tells Clark that she knows everything about him, but it's never explained.

> *Clark*: What'd you do to me?
>
> *Alicia*: Okay, don't get mad.
>
> *Clark*: How'd you know about the red kryptonite?
>
> *Alicia*: Because I know everything about you, Clark. We were meant to be together, remember? Just like you said.
>
> <sub>*[Episode script](https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/view_episode_scripts.php?tv-show=smallville&episode=s04e11)*</sub>

So, how did she know that she needed to use red kryptonite on Clark?

Answer (score 1):

In my early days of being a Smallville fan I wondered the same thing. But after rewatching the series -- including specifically Alicia's one episode in season three -- several times since, I developed a hunch.

My hunch is Alicia found out about the red kryptonite while rifling through Clark's things during the one season three episode. When she redecorated Clark's loft so it could be "more us now".

Although nothing was specifically stated about this, it seemed as if Clark had been out all day. For all we know Alicia could have been learning about Clark's entire background while in the process of redecorating the loft.

Also, Alicia may remember seeing Clark acting strangely when he was on red K, discovered the red K later on, and put two and two together. Just because we the audience didn't meet Alicia until the one season three episode doesn't mean Alicia didn't know Clark until then. She just didn't associate with him until she discovered his powers, that he was "different".

To tell you the truth, I can speculate on several more reasons Alicia knew about the red K. But instead I'm just going to make the point that it might not have been as hard for her to find that out as we fans might believe.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Do note however that answers based mostly or wholly on known facts are much preferred to answers which are mostly speculation.